# changing the tab order

Tags: c#, winforms

How do you change tab orders on the form when it is too complex like having splitters and again another splitter inside the first one and panels and activex controls and user controls and even some panels behind other panels to show/hide them based on the selection of a radio button,... I am attaching the picture also, for me it is even hard to visually find the control and select it especially when it is a panel under other panels...
so I took the route of overriding the **ProcessCmdKey** and manually handling tabbing and works great. but I cannot imagine there is no way to handle this with IDE... maybe easier to change the resx files? any thoughts?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Yes, in situations like this, I tend to edit the tab ordering manually as it's set up in the .designer files, and that works fine.  That's not easy either.

If possible, a better option would be to break down the complex form into smaller controls, set the tab ordering within them, and then compose them into the form.

Comment: you mean the Designer.cs file? I only found "TabStop" in there.

Comment: Yes the Designer.cs file.  There's a property in System.Windows.Forms.Control called TabIndex.  You can set this for each control.  The best way to get a feel for it might be to create a small dummy WinForms application, set the TabStops in the designer, then look at the .Designer.cs file code.  Reference:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tabindex.aspx